# body background color only being applied to the element

Tags: html, css

Just deleted all the code to be easier to solve it maybe. The body background color is only applied to the elements but not the entire page.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>The 2021 Frontend Developer Crash Course</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>mdada</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's running fine in the snippet, I'm not understanding the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add body `height` or `min-height`

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height:100vh;
    background: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>mdada</h1>
</body>
```